# Footer on bottom POSITION ABSOLUTE WILL NOT WORK

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, bottomnavigationview

I am designing a webpage with some per-defined styles.I would like to bottom align the footer so that when you load into the site it looks normal. When i try to do this by using "bottom:0;position:absolute" it works on desktop, but when you switch to mobile or laptop it overrides the other content and shows on top of it. I am attaching pictures: [image: Mobile], [image: Laptop], and what it's supposed to look like; [image: Laptop].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe show us some code or make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use position `bottom:0` only if body height less then window height.

```
if ($(document.body).height() < $(window).height()) {
    $('#footer').attr('style', ' position: absolute; bottom: 0;left: 0; right: 0;');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the element above it `position: relative`?

Also, it might not be necessary to use `position: absolute` for your footer. Keeping the footer at the bottom of your HTML and just using `position: relative` should work without a hitch.